# Microservices: How the databases organized behind the microservice

Tags: database, cloud, microservices

This is my first time reading about the microservices. Knowing that services is a subdivide system from a whole system which specialize in different domains. What about the data. I assumed all services using tradition db to store their data and data are stored distributed in different domain. What if there are data can belong in both of these domain services, what should I do with them.

E.g. A basket service (handling user shopping cart), and Payment service (handling payment of their order they have placed in the basket).

Maybe this isn't a great example, where do the product information to be stored.

In monolithic application, we have single database which stored the whole business data where each data will have reference to each other.

Comment: Different databases per service/context. Would help to read about bounded contexts -> https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html or check Chapter 3 in Building Microservices (Sam Newman)

Answer (score 0):

With the services we tend to ask one question who is source of truth?
In your case user adds item to the cart and there is service which keep tracks of what items the user has added (it may just have a itemid stored)
When this used to moves to checkout, there will be a checkout service which will then ask the cart service about the items in the users cart, apply in the cart logic. 
Thing to note is checkout service knows and care about the checkout process and it has no idea where to get the data of the items. Its just calls the right service and get the stuff it wants and apply the logic.
For checkout to payment you pass along userid cartid and other info and payment can make use of these information to bloat the information as it sees fit and return a response back to checkout which may trigger an order service.

So if you see data is always available with one service and when ever you have a situation where you need data, instead of making a db call you make a service call
(Service responsibility is to give you this data with low latency and may be pulling in logic to cache or whatever)

Another point with respect to data is source of truth. For order service, which is called often we tend to keep a copy of all the information related to the order in it (Again we do that, their may be better approaches) and in doing so often during a return flow question which system to trust.You may query an order service to get an address on which order is supposed to be shipped, but this address might have been deleted by the user.

This is where Single source of truth comes into play. This is little tricky, for delivery service source of truth for delivery address is what it gets from order service and not the user service (however order service picked up the details from user service at time of placing orders)
At the same time, during return flow we consider the prices as stored in order service (again a snapshot of what was there during the time order was placed) not necessarily make a call to product service, however for payments we talk to payment service directly to check amount we have taken from the user (There may be multiple inward and outward flows)

So bottom line is

- Have one database exposed via one service, and let other service connect to db via this service
- Read more about Single Source of Truth. We decided on certain contracts like who is the SSOT for whom (I do not necessarily agree with this approach but it works well for us)